# Any advantage of using np.add(), np.divide(), etc. compared to +, /, etc.?

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I came across some codes that look like this:

```
a = np.divide(np.subtract(b, c), np.add(d, e))
```

In which a, b, c, d, e are all np.ndarray. This code line looks harder-to-understand compared to

```
a = (b-c)/(d+e)
```

Is there any advantage of using np.add(), np.divide(), etc. compared to +, /, etc. ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: There are additional arguments that the methods take.  For example, if you want to operate and store the result in an existing array, or you have a condition you want applied to the operation.

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.add` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) says that

> The `+` operator can be used as a shorthand for `np.add` on ndarrays.

Is there any advantage of using np.add(), np.divide(), etc. compared to +, /, etc. ?

`np.add` is first class citizien, so you might for example do

```
def myfunction(arr1, arr2, action):
    return action(arr1,arr2)
```

and used it like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
total = myfunction(a,b,np.add)
```

rather than doing something like

```
def myfunction(arr1, arr2, action):
    if action=="+":
        return arr1 + arr2
    elif action=="/":
        return arr1 / arr2
    ...
```

Please also note that if arguments are **not** `numpy`s array you might other result than using just `+`, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
print(a+b) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(np.add(a,b)) # [5 7 9]
```